# Не могу разобраться как отпарсить txt файл с помощью Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, txt

из папки D:\logs скопировать в папку D:\backup *.txt файлы содержащие в тексте Errors

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: из папки в папку нужно вытащить все строки,где есть слово error

Comment: Ту не надо ничего парсить.читаешь файл, если внутри есть слово error, то копируешь его куда надо. С чем конкретно проблемы?

Comment: я не понимаю как это кодом выразить

Answer (score 1):

Python файл лежит в основной папке.
В папке с файлом python есть две папки.
Папка 1 содержит .txt файлы, которые нужно проверить.
Папка 2 пустая, в неё будут перемещены файлы.

```
import glob
import os
import shutil

file_destination = r'C:\*\2\\' #полный путь к папке, куда нужно перенести файлы

word = u'Errors' #Слово, которое ищем
failse = []
for filename in glob.glob('1\*.txt'):
   with open(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), filename), 'r', encoding="utf-8") as f:
       text = f.read()
       if word in text:
        failse.append(f.name)

for g in failse:
    shutil.move(g, file_destination)
```

Comment: Отступы только сделайте однотипные - по 4 пробела, а не то 1, то 3, то 4 )